# AWS Glue Job Fails with "WARN YarnClient: The GET request failed for the URL ..."

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Running a pretty standard Python Glue job that has been running on other files recently. With a new file the job is failing with the following log message "WARN YarnClient: The GET request failed for the URL [http://0.0.0.0:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1598...."](http://0.0.0.0:8088/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1598....%22) Does anyone know what the cause is? Could it be a permission error on the S3 Source?

Comment: Can you update your question with full stack trace and more details about the new file and any changes done to Glue job or the way it is executed?